# S1 contains s2 with regex

Tags: java, regex

Here is my problem:
I have 2 strings `s1` and `s2` as input and I need to find the initial position of `s2` in `s1`. `s2` has a `*` character in it that in regex stands for `*+`.

Example:

```
s1: "abcabcqmapcab"
s2: "cq*pc"
```

The output shoud be: `5`.

This is my code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class UsoAPIBis {

    /* I need to find the initial position of s2 in s1. 
    s2 contains a * that stands for any characters with any frequency. */

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("String1: ");
        String s1 = scan.next();
        System.out.print("String2: ");
        String s2 = scan.next();
        //it replace the star with the regex ".*" that means any char 0 or more more times.
        s2 = s2.replaceAll("\\*", ".*");
        System.out.printf("The starting position of %s in %s in %d", s2, s1, posContains);
    }

    //it has to return the index of the initial position of s2 in s1
    public static int indexContains(String s1, String s2) {
        if (s1.matches(".*"+s2+".*")) {
            //return index of the match;
        }
        else {
            return -1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey Chetan, ty, but my code was old and wrong, i've edited with the right code, with the right goal. thank you.

Comment: Wow. That's a drastic change in the requirements.

Comment: With the example, you can understand easy what i mean. thank you

Comment: I am not sure what is the problem here. Why won't you simply use `s1.indexOf(s2)`? Why do you want to involve regex? Also what is the point of `matches` here? This method checks if entire string can be matched by regex, not how many times regex can be found in strings.

Comment: Hi Pshemo, 'cos in s2 i can use the *, and with the star the user means any character with any frequency. Example: a*z = abcdddfhtlotz. So you need to use Regex.

Comment: Updated the code, s1.matches(".*"+s2+".*") works, checked with java repl

Comment: I think s2 is supposed to represent a glob pattern.

Comment: any help with the return in the method? Please, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean that `*` in your given string should represent `.+` or `.*` and not `*+`. The `.` character in the regex means "any character", `+` means "one or more times" and `*` means "zero or more times" (greedily).

In this case, you can use this:

```
public class Example {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String s1 = "abcabcqmapcab";
        String s2 = "cq*pc";

        String pattern = s2.replaceAll("\\*", ".+"); // or ".*"
        Matcher m = Pattern.compile(pattern).matcher(s1);
        if (m.find())
            System.out.println(m.start());
    }
}
```

Output:

```
5
```

Comment: Amazing, thank you. I think I need to study Pattern and Matcher :=))!!

Comment: @DrwMay [`Pattern`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) has the documentation for regex in Java and [Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/index.html) is the tutorial.